# Automatic slideshow with multiple images and no duplicates

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I need to make two separate slideshows which automatically changes images with no controls whatsoever, but there should not be the same images in both the slideshows at the same time.

I added a small function to check for this, and if both images were the same, I traversed my order by 1.

Unfortunately my function is not running all the time, but only after the first image is selected and if it does not match the image in the second image, it does not do anything.

I need my function to run whenever the images presently shown matches with each other, and if it does change one of the image. Here is my simple code:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfv32vfq/)

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

var slideIndex1 = 0;
showSlides1();

function showSlides1() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex1++;
    if ((slideIndex1> slides.length)&&$('.mySlides img').attr('src')==$('.mySlides1 img').attr('src')) {slideIndex1 = 1}

    slides[slideIndex1-1].style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(showSlides1,2000); // Change image every 2 seconds

}
if($('.mySlides img').attr('src')==$('.mySlides1 img').attr('src'))
        slideIndex1++;
```

Comment: You have 34 views, don't worry, someone will answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using two functions, use only one to display images from both.

```
    <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    var maximum = 2;
    var minimum = 0;
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var slides1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");; 

    $(".mySlides").css('display','none');
    $(".mySlides1").css('display','none');


    var randomnumber1;
    var randomnumber2;

    showSlides();

    function showSlides() {

        randomnumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;

       // run this loop until randomnumber1 is different than randomnumber2
        do {
            randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
        } while(randomnumber1 === randomnumber2);

       console.log(randomnumber1 + "," + randomnumber2);

        $(".mySlides").css('display','none');
        $(".mySlides1").css('display','none');

        slides[randomnumber1].style.display = "block";

        slides1[randomnumber2].style.display = "block";

        setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted! thanx mate ; I always thought a random function would be better than a constant order

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities you could do.  Here are my thoughts:

I'm not too eager to create two functions that do essentially the same thing.  I would suggest creating one function that would loop through each `.slideshow-container`, find the nth child that is showing, hide them, then show the next child.  Once you have looped through each `.slideshow-container` and displayed the next `img`, check to see if the img src is the same.  If so, bump the child of one of the containers.

but...

Since both slideshows iterate at the same time, the approach I would use (as is is much less code) is to create your div's with only one image and assign it an id.  I changed the width for the fiddle:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="image1" class="slideshow-image" style="width: 300px;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-container" style="margin-top:0px;border:1px red solid">
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img id="image2" class="slideshow-image" style="width: 300px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, put all the `img` sources in an array and assign each one of the images a starting index (more pics added for show).  Also, attach the `data` element that stores the index:

```
var slides = [
    'http://www.newsread.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Images-13.jpg',
    'http://free.clipartof.com/176-Free-Cartoon-Owl-Clipart.jpg',
    'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg',
    'http://cdn-2.butterflypictures.net/images/14-free-butterfly-clip-art-l.jpg',
    'http://www.newsread.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Images-3.jpg',
    'http://images.clipartpanda.com/offense-clipart-jRiGGgAcL.gif'
];

$('#image1').attr('src', slides[0]);
$('#image1').data('index', 0);
$('#image2').attr('src', slides[Math.floor(slides.length / 2)]);
$('#image2').data('index', Math.floor(slides.length / 2));
```

Then, create a function that will loop through each `img` (by class `slideshow-image`) and iterate it to the next index.  You have included jQuery so this function uses it as well.

```
function showSlides() {
    setInterval(function() {
    $('.slideshow-image').each(function(iter) {
      $this = $(this);
      var newIndex = ($this.data('index') + 1) % slides.length;
      // iterate the image
      $this.attr('src', slides[newIndex]);
      // set the new index
      $this.data('index', newIndex);
    });
  }, 2000);
}
```

That's it.  I've left out the fades, but you could style it however you like.  Keep in mind that the fiddle shows images loading at different times but that's because their source `img` is rather large.  I wouldn't expect yours to do this.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfv32vfq/2/).

Comment: Wow this certainly opens up new possibilities for me to think about.. btw where did you match the src of the images to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Where you set the image src `$('#image2').attr('src', slides[Math.floor(slides.length / 2)]);`.  If one image starts at 0 and the other image starts at the length of the image array / 2 (6/2=3), this would make the second image start at 3.  They both iterate together, so they will never be on the same array index.  That's why I felt that your approach was overkill.  You shouldn't need the function to check if the images are the same then reverse one of them, just start at different index's of the array.

Comment: Oh cool...must say that is way better than my approach but i thought because i dont know how many images or silders i need so i went with that approach. Thanx a lot! will try to implement your way too